# How do I search from a local cache with pip?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

How do I make sure pip uses my local pypi server when searching for packages ?
When I hit pip install, using the following pip.conf, it hit's my local pypi server, but not when searching for packages.

I've got the following ~/.pip/pip.conf

```
[global]
default-timeout = 60
respect-virtualenv = true
download-cache = ~/.pip/cache
log-file = ~/.pip/pip.log
build = ~/.pip/build
index-url = http://localhost:8181/simple

[install]
use-mirrors = true

[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    local

[local]
index-url = http://localhost:8181/simple
```

Comment: try to swap `pypi` and `local` in `index-servers`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that didn't help